# Most efficient way to roll back data. To turn back time

Tags: c++, arrays

So, I have a 3d platformer.  And I want to have a button that if you hold it it makes you "go back in time".  Thankfully the game is rather simple and only has one entity so the only thing that would have to be saved for each frame is.

```
struct Coord {
float x;
float y;
float z;
}

structure Bool6 {
bool front;
bool back;
bool left;
bool right;
bool top;
bool bottom;
}

struct Player {
Coord Pos;
Coord Vel;
Bool6 Col;
}
```

But I fear that is a lot of data especially since my game theoretically runs somewhere around 60fps and it would be good to have 5 seconds or so (300 frames) of data saved that can be accessed when roll-backed.  I have considered each frame doing something like this

```
Player Data[300];

for (int i = 299; i > 0; i--)
{
   Data[i] = Data[(i-1)];
}
Data[0] = "THIS FRAMES DATA";
```

However that sounds like it means an outrageous amount of processing power is going just in storing each frame.

Is their a more efficient way to store this data keeping all of the data in order?

Also is their a way I can tell an array slot that it has nothing?  So that their arent problems if the player tries to rollback before all of the array slots are filled or after rolling back?  I believe in C# i would have set it equal to NULL... but that doesn't work in c++ probably because im using structures.

Thanks much!

Comment: Why would you need to "go back" *frame by frame*? Wouldn't it be sufficient to, for example, store the player's control input with a timestamp, then work your way back? Anyway, your last paragraph makes me think a "3D platformer" is well beyond your grasp of the language...

Comment: Maybe you don't have to store 300 frames, only one every 10ms for example, because all you need is to roll back, not replay in reverse, no ?

Comment: You could use a ring buffer (google it), but on a modern machine your simple solution may not even make a dent in the frame rate. I would stick with it until it proves problematic. Write a useful abstraction so you can swap the implementation transparently, of course.

Comment: @DevSolar probably the best way to do this without killing the processor.  However my movement code is so basic, and my knowledge of 3d math so non existent that that wouldn't be a good solution for my game.  However it is probably the best solution.

Comment: Have a look at [this question](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/15251/how-to-implement-time-traveling-into-a-game) in which the implementation of such a mechanic is discussed.

Comment: one small improvement: `front .. back` are mutually exclusive. So instead of 6 `bool` you can have one `enum`. If you have `c++11` you can set the underlining type to `char` to store it in only one byte. I strongly suspect however that this will have almost no performance impact (measure it!), so you are probably better with your 6 `bool` structure

Answer (score 2):

> However that sounds like it means an outrageous amount of processing power

Before making such a statement it can be useful to do the math. It seems the data you are concerned with is about 40 bytes, so 40*300 = 12 kB. This can easily fit in memory and is far from an "outrageous amount of processing power" on modern computers.

> Is their a more efficient way to store this data keeping all of the data in order?

Yes. If your game is deterministic, all you have to store is the player's input and one game state 5 seconds ago. When rolling back, reset the game state and replay user inputs to recompute each frame data.

See [this question](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/6080/how-to-design-a-replay-system) for interesing discussion on how to design your own replay system on gamedev stackexchange.

Comment: It's actually ~40 bytes * 300 frames = 12 kB.

Comment: `This can easily fit in L1 cache` - fixed that for you ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think an array of 300 relatively small elements will slow you down at all, have you tried profiling it yet?

That said you could store it in a vector and keep an iterator to the "current" and update that.

Comment: I have actually not demoed this code.  Unfortunately the computer I code on is really beefy and the one it will be finally displayed on is not.  I have to be super careful.  Also I have not set up any fps or dt counters yet.  However that is on the agenda.   What do you mean store it in a vector?  Like instead of storing the raw data just store what changed and by how much?

Comment: @Andrew you should try to run your code in a virtual machine. This is going to be as "un-beefy" as desired.

Answer (score 0):

If you  think storing 300 is a lot, store less, for example you can store 1/5 frames :

`....|....|....|....|..*`

```
* is your position, `/` the frames you will store and `....` other frames
```

and you don't have to copy all the saved data each time ... just delete the first and add one at the end, you can maybe use a std::list, you won't have to copy any data

in Every 5 frames you will call  `myList.pop_front();` the oldest frame and `myList.push_back();` the newest

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the storage requirement is THAT harsh - even with 300 frames this small object will take up much less memory than your average texture.

I suggest you avoid using a raw array and look at using a std::vector which is almost as efficient and will automatically resize as you need more buffer space (that way if you suddenly need 8 second or the fps goes up to 100 you aren't going to suddenly run out of buffer space). This also resolves your difficulty with unfilled 'slots' as the vector has a known size that you can efficiently access.

I also might suggest that you don't need to store every frame - games like Prince of Persia that do this trick if you watch them carefully are much less smooth when time runs backwards suggesting that they perhaps only store every few frames or something like twice a second as opposed to every frame.

Comment: Vector is definetely not a good way to store data here... First he has to do many copies everytime he wants to store a frame. and vector do additionnal copies when he needs to resize ... That makes a lot of copies, while he can do it without a single copy

Comment: @OthmanBenchekroun `std::vector` is almost always a good idea. It is one of the best implemented data structures in the `std`. It does not copy when it resizes, but when it increases capacity. If you want to be extra safe, you can `reserve` immediate after declaration.

Comment: @bolov  he will still have to do 299 copies each time he stores a frame... Circular bufer or list are more interesting I think

Comment: @OthmanBenchekroun I agree that his current implementation shifting the whole vector is a bad idea. I would stay away from `lists` because they are very cache-unfriendly (I actually measured on a game with many inserts and deletes from random positions every frame and vector actually did performed marginally better that a list). My goto solution here would be as you said a circular buffer implemented with a vector. Very easy to implement.

Comment: @OthmanBenchekroun Vector is very efficiently implemented - as the storage head towards it's maximum (say 300) the vector (assuming it wasn't preallocated to 300 size) might resize two or three times but it doesn't resize and copy each time it needs to add an element - similarly after it reaches this maximum (Presumably after the first 5 seconds) size it doesn't reallocate  at all as it gets smaller and larger. A simple circular buffer implementation is still a good idea but I would build it on top of a vector.

Comment: @Elemental I agree, I was saying that using Vector in the way he is using an array wouldn't be a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

1. Unless you're running on an MCU, data sizes (given the structures you've provided) will be negligible compared to the rest of your game (~10K, if I calculated it correctly, is nothing for modern PCs).
2. CPU-wise, moving data in a manner you've specified and on every frame, MIGHT be sub-optimal (it will move around 10K 60 times per second, or 600K per second, which MIGHT - though probably won't - be noticeable). IF it becomes a concern, I'd go for a circular buffer (for example, as in boost::circular_buffer), or for a std::deque or std::list (with deque probably being my first choice); all of them have O(1) insertion/deletion time, and insertion/deletion is what you need most of the time. Theoretically, there is also an option to use memmove() to speed things up without changing things much, but it is quite error-prone, and still has O(N) complexity, so I'd rather not do it.

Answer (score -2):

Indeed, you could do less operations per frame to store the state.

You could use a `std::vector`. Then, at each frame, `push_back()` the new state and `if(vector.size() > 300)`, then do a `pop_front()`.

If you think it's not enough, just save less frequently (each half a second). When you roll back your info, you could do an interpolation between values.

---

### Edit:

you're damn right Othman, vector doesn't have pop_front, so you can use vector.erase(vector.begin()) instead :) So you don't have to use linked lists.

Comment: `std::vector` doesn't have a pop_front() function

Comment: Ok I don't understand the down votes. The answer has been edited so it is now correct

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/erase/  erasing data in vectors is costly, because the objects that are after the removed data will be moved to new position, list is different, however a vector can still be used here as a circular buffer implementation